# Using attribute 'title' to change css items

Tags: jquery, css, title

Just trying to get it to restyle each element depending on the content within the title
so far, it only changes it based on the first one and ignores the other ones.
When I use "each()" it should be checking each one and then changing the color to red for no blue for yes.

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>colorme</title>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2      /jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


 $(".test").each(function(){ 

 var title = $(this).find('.taskName').attr("title");
    if(title =="yes") {
   $('div.taskName').css('color','blue');

    }
 else if(title =="no")  {
     $('div.taskName').css('color','red');

    }
});

});


</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
<div class="taskName" title="yes">this should  be blue</div>
<div class="taskName" title="no">this should not be blue</div>
<div class="taskName" title="yes">this should  be blue</div>
<div class="taskName" title="no">this should not be blue</div>
</div>


</body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not avoid selecting `.test` and just select `.taskname`

```
 $(".taskName").each(function(){ 
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
    if(title =="yes") {
        $(this).css('color','blue');

    }else if(title =="no")  {
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
var $div = $('div.taskName');
$div.filter('[title=yes]').css('color', 'blue');
$div.filter('[title=no]').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: @undefined, beat you by a few secs but with syntax error, lol. Thx for edit.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without jQuery or JavaScript.  Pure CSS:

```css
.taskName[title='yes']
{
    color: blue;
}
.taskName[title='no']
{
    color: red;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/KSyn3](http://jsfiddle.net/KSyn3/)

Answer (score 1):

`.attr` will only select the *first* attribute that is found.  `$("div.taskName")` also affects *all* attributes.  You need to iterate over each both to get the title and to get the correct div to update.  You can do this at once, though:

```
$(".test").each(function(){ 
    $(this).find('.taskName').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        if ('yes' == title) {
            $(this).css('color', 'blue');
        }
        else if ('no' == title) {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/qrRGN/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the good code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".taskName").each(function(){ 

        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        if(title =="yes") {
            $(this).css('color','blue');

        }
        else if(title =="no")  {
            $(this).css('color','red');

        }
    });

});
```

Your error came from the fact that you were using `div.taskName` as your jQuery selector. As a result, it target **all** taskName, not just the current one.

That's why you need to use the keyword "this", so that, every time the loop is run, it targets a *different* element.

Also, I changed the target of the loop. That way, you don't need to use the `find()` function. It's faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.taskName[title="yes"]').css('color', 'blue');
$('.taskName[title="no"]').css('color', 'red');
```

Also has the benefit of using querySelectorAll on browsers which support it.

Comment: Fantastic, and now for some history as to why I wanted to do things this way: -It comes in handy if you have to make changes to SELECT Items in a hierchy that all have the same class name -The task was to make "top level" items Bolder than lesser "children" the trouble was they had the same classes, BUT all lower level elements were given the same TITLE -apart from the top-level items! Problem solved. Thanks for all the help!